# How to use ToShortDateString in linq lambda expression?

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework

I need to call ToShortDateString in a linq query suing lambda expressions:

```
toRet.Notification = Repositories
    .portalDb.portal_notifications.OrderByDescending(p =>       p.id)
    .FirstOrDefault(p => p.date.ToShortDateString() == shortDateString);
```

but I get the error:

> An exception of type 'System.NotSupportedException' occurred in
>   System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method
>   'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be
>   translated into a store expression.

What can I do, considering that I do need to use `ToShortDateString()` ?

Thanks.

Comment: This thread may help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5370402/entity-framework-4-linq-how-to-convert-from-datetime-to-string-in-a-query

Comment: This thread should help:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233495/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't be forcing a string comparison when what you're working with is Date/time data - as soon as you force string comparisons, you're suddenly having to deal with *how* the strings are formatted.

Instead, have something like:

```
var endDate = targetDate.AddDays(1);

toRet.Notification = Repositories
.portalDb.portal_notifications.OrderByDescending(p =>       p.id)
.FirstOrDefault(p => p.date >= targetDate && p.date < endDate);
```

(Assuming that `targetDate` is whatever `DateTime` variable you had that was used to produce `shortDateString` in your code, and is already a `DateTime` with no time value)

Comment: I was looking for solution to this issue as well. Within database I may have dates like 2012-06-06 20:14:50.367. When looking for records that are posted on 2012.06.06 I have to convert date I search for from 2012.06.06 to 2012.06.05 23:59 or go for similar trick. I wanted to avoid it by removing the time component somehow but not from the searching date but dates in the database. Greets for everyone. really nice portal, lot's of useful info.

Answer (score 24):

Linq to Entities cannot convert `ToSortDateString` method into SQL code. You can't call it on server side. Either move filtering to client side (that will transfer all data from server to client), or consider to use [server-side functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd395596.aspx) to take date part of date (you should pass `DateTime` object instead of `shortDateString`):

```
EntityFunctions.TruncateTime(p.date) == dateWithoutTime
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response. After writing FirstOrDefault(p => (EntityFunctions.TuncateTime(p.date) == shortDateString) I received the error An exception of type 'System.Data.EntityCommandExecutionException' occurred in System.Data.Entity.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: An error occurred while executing the command definition. See the inner exception for details.

If there is a handler for this exception, the program may be safely continued.

Comment: @OctavianEpure as I stated above, instead of passing string `shortDateString` you should pass `DateTime` object

Comment: Using EF6, I had to use `DbFunctions.TruncateTime()`

Comment: using System.Data.Entity;
.Select(a => DbFunctions.TruncateTime(a.MyDate))

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

You can also used with below code.

```
Activity = String.Format("{0} {1}", String.Format("{0:dd-MMM-yyyy}", s.SLIDESHEETDATE), String.Format("{0:HH:mm}", s.ENDDATETIME))
```

Answer (score -3):

`ToShortDateString()` method usually used to work only with date and ignore time stamps.

You will get exactly today result-set by using the following query.

```
Repositories.portalDb.portal_notifications.OrderByDescending(p =>       p.id)
        .FirstOrDefault(p => p.date.Date == DateTime.Now.Date);
```

By using `Date` property of `DateTime` struct you can just fetch record of that date only.

Note: Linq to Objects. Only works if you CAN (or have option) to bypass `ToShortDateString()` method

Comment: `p.date.Date` will throw an exception. You can't do that in a LINQ to Entities query.

Comment: You misunderstood me. `date` is a `DateTime` type property here. you can change it with `CreatedDate`. First look the question please ...

Comment: I understand that `date` is a `DateTime` property. What I'm saying is that you can't use `date.Date` in LINQ to Entities since it doesn't know how to translate that into SQL.

Comment: you can take this `p.CreatedDate.Date`. hope you get it :-)

Comment: Yes that's when you're translating to `ToShortDateString` from `Date` in Linq query. You can do manipulation on `Date` object in Linq. If I understand you correctly.

Comment: That's fine in LINQ to Objects, but *not* LINQ to Entities.