# LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method in MVC 4

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-migrations

I'm working with MVC 4 and I have to update my database using Code First Migrations.  What I'm trying to do is to select records from a database table, and insert them into a dropdown list where the user can select one.

I have an error that I don't understand:

`LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.`

**Controller:**

```
  public ActionResult Addnew()
        {
            var dba = new DefaultConnection();
            var query = dba.blob.Select(c => new SelectListItem
            {
                Value = c.id.ToString(),
                Text = c.name_company,
                Selected = c.id.Equals(3)
            });
            var model = new Companylist
            {
                xpto = query.AsEnumerable()
            };

            return View(model);
        }
```

Comment: [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities) should fix ya

Comment: or just use LinqToObjects instead.

Answer (score 67, accepted):

You got this error because Entity Framework does not know how to execute `.ToString()` method in sql. So you should load the data by using `ToList` and then translate into SelectListItem as:

```
var query = dba.blob.ToList().Select(c => new SelectListItem
    {
    Value = c.id.ToString(),
    Text = c.name_company,
    Selected = c.id.Equals(3)
});
```

Edit: To make it more clear, Entity framework converts your use of query operators such as `Select`, `Where` ETC into an sql query to load the data. If you call a method like `ToString()`, which Entity Framework does not have an equivalent in sql, it will complain. SO the idea is to defer the use of such functions post data load. `ToList`, `ToArray` ETC force execution of the query thus loading of data. Once the data is loaded, any further operation (such as `Select`, `Where` ETC) is performed using Linq to Objects, on the data already in memory.

Comment: The main problem with this approach, what if you select from a table with thousands, or tens of thousands of records - ToList will pull them all down from the database into an object, which you then do yet another select on. Highly inefficient - better to use SqlFunctions: Value = SqlFunctions.StringConvert(c.id)

Comment: Amazing explanation both VarunK and NaytGrochowski

Answer (score 2):

What if... you use:

```
Value = c.id + "",
```

instead of

```
Value = c.id.ToString(),
```

**Edit**

With this option, you are not retrieving all data from Database

Answer (score 0):

just use delegate :

```
var query = dba.blob.Select(delegate(blob c)
{
    return new SelectListItem
        {
            Value = c.id.ToString(),
            Text = c.name_company,
            Selected = c.id.Equals(3)
        };
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is how I do it to display as a SelectList.

```
 public List<BlobEntity> GetBlobs()
    {
        List<BlobEntity> blobs = null;
        using (var db = new MyDBEntities())
        {
            blobs = (from b in db.blobs
                     where b.id > 0 //Example filter
                     select new BlobEntity
                     {
                         ID = b.id,
                         CompanyName = b.name_company
                     }
                     ).ToList();

        }
        return blobs;
    }

   public static SelectList GetBlobsSelectList()
    {
        MyBL theBL = new MyBL();
        List<BlobEntity> blobEntites = theBL.GetBlobs();
        var listItems = blobEntites
             .Select(x => new SelectListItem { Text = x.CompanyName,
                                                Value = x.ID.ToString()
                                             })
             .ToList();
        SelectList blobsSelectList = new SelectList(listItems.AsEnumerable(), "Value", "Text");
        return blobsSelectList;
    }

   public class BlobEntity
   {
       public int ID { get; set; }
       public string CompanyName { get; set; }
   }
```

The current accepted answer (by @VarunK) is okay if you are selecting all records and all columns. However, if that is not the case, it is better to do a projection with required columns and records before applying `ToList()`.

Take a look at **[Why LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10110266/why-linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring/43262421#43262421)**.

Other references: [Problem with converting int to string in Linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities)