# linq to entities can not convert int to string

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, entity-framework

I try to filtering the data that return to kendo combo box, the filtering is based on the ID,
I need to return all records that contains the filtration text not only the equals one, so what I did is to cast the ID to string as the following snip

```
Items = Mapper.Map<List<PurchaseOrder>, List<PurchaseOrderViewModel>>(
                purchaseOrderRepository.GetMany(x => 
                                                x.PurchaseOrderID
                                                 .ToString()
                                                 .Contains(text))
                                                 .ToList());
```

but it's always return 
linq to entities does not recognize the method 'system.string tostring()'

so I tried to convert the dbset to list before the where statement as I found in another post
[LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method in MVC 4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233495/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method)
but I got another error says that the list does not contains a definition for Where (dbSet is an instance of IDbSet)

```
public virtual IList<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
{

    return dbset.ToList().Where(where).ToList();
}
```

here is My original(current) get method

```
sing System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq.Expressions;
using Spine.ERP.DataAccess.DbFirstDataAccess;
using Spine.ERP.DataModel.Helpers;
namespace Spine.ERP.DataAccess.Infrastructure
{
    public abstract class RepositoryBase<T> where T : class
    {

        private SSSDBEntities dataContext;

        private readonly IDbSet<T> dbset;

        protected RepositoryBase(IDatabaseFactory databaseFactory)
        {
            DatabaseFactory = databaseFactory;
            dbset = DataContext.Set<T>();
        }

       protected IDatabaseFactory DatabaseFactory
        {
            get;
            private set;
        }


        protected SSSDBEntities DataContext
        {
            get { return dataContext ?? (dataContext = DatabaseFactory.Get()); }
        }
    public virtual IQueryable<T> GetMany(Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
        {
            return dbset.Where(where);
        }
  }
}
```

Any other thing can I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is a [SqlFunctions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions_methods%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class available that contains many SQL-functions that may be used for LINQ. Try a look at `SqlFunctions.StringConvert`

```
Items = Mapper.Map<List<PurchaseOrder>, List<PurchaseOrderViewModel>>(
                purchaseOrderRepository
                   .GetMany(x => SqlFunctions
                                  .StringConvert((double?) x.PurchaseOrderID)
                                  .Contains(text))
                                  .ToList());
```

Unfortunately there is only a `SqlFunctions.StringConvert(double? number)` and no `SqlFunctions.StringConvert(int? number)`. But I always convert the integer number to a double and it works as expected.

Edit: You are calling `ToList` prior `Where`. Therefore that SqlFunctions can only be called in a `LINQ to Entity query` any SqlFunctions after a `ToList()` is illegal.

Try without your GetMany Method:

```
purchaseOrderRepository.Set<PurchaseOrder>()
   .Where(x => SqlFunctions
       .StringConvert((double?) x.PurchaseOrderID)
       .Contains(text))
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply but I try this solution before but the same error return

Comment: Stange, it should work. I have never had a problem with that. I cannot see the reason why with this code the same error should arise. Are you somewhere calling `ToString()`

Comment: No I didn't call ToString() anywhere

Comment: I cannot understand why you get exactly the same error. At least it should be different.

(I have edited the above code: not the cast ist to double? instead of double; maybe thats the problem)

Comment: Thank for your help, but it's still raise the same error maybe it should convert to List first then filtering, but I can not do that because it's always return that the where not found

Comment: Ok, now I have seen that you call `ToList` prior `Where`. Therefore you cannot call any SqlFunction.

Try executing it directly

purchaseOrderRepository.Where(x => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?) x.PurchaseOrderID).Contains(text)).ToList());

Comment: Thanks again, get many is the method which will get the data from the data base and the repository is just and interface to allow me using this method, so i can't call Where from the repository direct.

Comment: I add the GetMany method which I currently used

Comment: Is there any possibility that you can call Where to a repository.Set<PurchaseOrder>(), just to see if my proposed solution would work in your case?

Comment: I't not work, it's return a syntax error says that the class does not contain a definition for Where

Comment: Of what type is purchaseOrderRepository? Is it a DbContext?

Comment: Then you should be able to call:
purchaseOrderRepository.Set<PurchaseOrder>().Where(x => SqlFunctions.StringConvert((double?) x.PurchaseOrderID).Contains(text)

Comment: I tired it as I say before but its not recognized the Where statement it's raise syntax error says that its contain a definition for Where

Comment: Have you imported System.Linq?

Comment: Yes for sure, I add the base class to my original post

Comment: Sorry my bad, it's recognized it but it's raise syntax error when use it

Comment: Now I am a little bit confused. Intellisense suggests the method where, but by using it you get a syntax error?

Comment: That what confusing me also, When I user DBContext<T>.Where() it's work, but when I user DBContext<PurchaseOrder>.Where() it's return an error also same error returns when I use DBContext<T>.ToList().Where()

Comment: No, you should use DataContext.Set<PurchaseOrder>().Where(...)

Comment: Sorry that what I mean DbContext.set<Class>.Where not DBContext<class>

Comment: System.Data.Entity.DBSet<PurchaseOrder> does not contain a definition for Where and the best extension method overload System.Liqe.Enumerable.Where<TSource>(System.Collection.Generic.IEnumerable<TSource,int,bool>) has some invalid arguments

Comment: That is very, very strange. Than lets at least try DataContext.PurchaseOrder.Where(...)

Comment: That seems impossible for me. I do the same all the time. Normally this error arises if System.Linq is not imported. You have importe this reference also in the sub-class right?

Comment: Strange, I will try this tonight and let you know whether I have any strange problems.

Comment: I have tried it, and the above code did not raise any syntax Errors (surely I have modified the type and property to my Needs ;) )

Comment: Thank you, I'll double check my code again and check what is wrong with it