# Use "Sum" Into Select new class

Tags: c#, linq, select, sum

I have a linq query that returns a public class. In select new I access a property Cruising through entities database and add the value but jumps except where it says:

LINQ to Entities does not recognize the 'System.String ToString ()' method of the method, and this method can not be translated into a store expression.

where is the problem? I can navigate in a Linq .Select across linq to bd navigation properties really?

I tried to make the .Sum of several ways but I failed.

I would appreciate help.

thanks

```
  public class prueba
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Codigo { get; set; }
    public string Total { get; set; }

}
var result = db.cliente
                       .Where(p => !p.Baja.Value)
                       .Where(OperacionPedido(operacionPedid, numPedidos))
                       .Where(OperacionGastado(operacionTot, totGastado))
                       .Select(p => new prueba
                       {
                           Id = p.Id,
                           Nombre = p.Nombre + " " + p.Apellidos,
                           Email = p.Email,
                           Codigo = p.territorio1.Codigo_iso3166_3.Trim(),
                           Total = p.pedido.Sum(oo=>oo.Total.Value).ToString() 
                       }).OrderBy(p => p.Nombre)
                       .ToList();
```

Comment: As the error suggests, the problem is not in `Sum`, but in `ToString`. I'd suggest making `Total` an numeric type, so you don't have to call `ToString`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, - MVC4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233495/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method)

Comment: Thanks p.s.w.g,

your solution is good, I preferred to return a string but in the end will be better to return a decimal. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [`SqlFunctions.StringConvert`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd466166.aspx) instead of `ToString` so your Sum query

```
Total = p.pedido.Sum(oo=>oo.Total.Value).ToString()
```

should be:

```
Total = SqlFunctions.StringConvert(p.pedido.Sum(oo=>oo.Total.Value))
```

LINQ queries with Entity framework translates into underlaying data source language, *(in your case SQL probably)*, and `ToString` can't be translated into SQL by Entity framework. That is why `SqlFunctions.StringConvert` is provided.

It is not a good idea to store numeric value in `String` type, instead you should use `int` or `double` type for your field `Total`.

Comment: The only caveat is that `SqlFunction` will tie you (and work only) with SQL Server.

Comment: Right Simon and Habib, is good solution too but in the end i'll to return a decimal and i will not return string.

Thanks very much