# EF - Query Large Data Sets Causes Out Of Memory Exception

Tags: c#, sql, xml, entity-framework

I have a data table with several xml fields. I'm using EF to get the data using where:

```
List<tblMSASAN> msa = ctx.tblMSASANs.Where(s => s.LCMGSupportLevel != "decommissioned").ToList();
```

Then using a foreach to iterate the list and pulling the xml field into an xmldocument and querying each node updating an attribute, then saving the context.

However, the dataset is too large and I get an out of memory exception.
So I need to be able to query the xml first to return a smaller dataset.

```
List<tblWinServer> servers = ctx.tblWinServers.AsNoTracking().Where(s => s.LCMGSupportLevel != "decommissioned" && ( Convert.ToString(s.TapeDrives).Contains("Calyx") ||Convert.ToString(s.DiskShelves).Contains("Calyx"))).ToList();
```

But this doesn't work with a NotSupportedException.

Any ideas?

Comment: possible duplicate of [LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, - MVC4](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233495/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method).

Answer (score -1, accepted):

AsNoTracking() method returns IQueryable but if you want to use ToString() method in Where clause you have to convert IQueryable to IEnumerable:

```
List<tblWinServer> servers = ctx.tblWinServers.AsNoTracking().AsEnumerable().Where(s => s.LCMGSupportLevel != "decommissioned" && ( Convert.ToString(s.TapeDrives).Contains("Calyx") ||Convert.ToString(s.DiskShelves).Contains("Calyx"))).ToList();
```

Comment: This is exactly what the OP does *not* want: " the dataset is too large".