# need to use Count() for null and non null values in Linq

Tags: c#, linq, count

Here is my code:

```
var value = query.Select(
    a => new CHART_MODEL
        {
            TEXT = "xyz",
            COUNT1 = (a.TOPLAM_FIYAT != null).ToString().Count(),
            COUNT2 = (a.TOPLAM_FIYAT == null) ? ToString().Count() : 0
        }
     ).ToList();
```

Here is the error:

> System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

and CHART_MODEL

```
public class CHART_MODEL
{
  public int COUNT1 { get; set; }
  public int COUNT2 { get; set; }
  public string TEXT { get; set; }
}
```

My question is: I have to calculate null and non null values with Count(). but it doesn't allow me to write. I don't know how to rearrange linq query code in correct way with Count().

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18233495/linq-to-entities-does-not-recognize-the-method-system-string-tostring-method

and: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Problem with converting int to string in Linq to entities](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1066760/problem-with-converting-int-to-string-in-linq-to-entities)

Comment: I don't understand why you're trying to use `ToString()` here at all. If you want to count something, why is `ToString` involved?

Answer (score 1):

This is an error you get because EF doesn't know how to execute the `.ToString()` method in sql.

Methods like that which EF doesn't have correlated methods in plain sql, will throw an error like the one you received.
What you can do is use an **Immediate Execution**.methods like: `ToList` or `ToArray`  will force the execution of the query, hence loading the data into memory and when the data is loaded the rest of the operators are performed using Linq to objects on that the data that was brought in memory.

So, you can load the data using `toList()` and after that use the rest of the code and methods like `toString()` won't throw an error.

```
query.toList().Select(..)
```

You can read more about Deferred Execution vs Immediate Execution here:
https://samirbehara.com/2016/01/04/deferred-execution-vs-immediate-execution-in-linq/

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way would be something like

```
var value = new  CHART_MODEL
{
    TEXT = "xyz",
    COUNT1 = query.Where(a=>a.TOPLAM_FIYAT != null).Count(),
    COUNT2 = query.Where(a=>a.TOPLAM_FIYAT == null).Count() 
};
```

Note, this will issue two select statements.

If you really want to avoid the two select statements, you have to introduce a dummy grouping such as

```
var value = (from r in query
         group r by 1 into results
         select new  CHART_MODEL
         {
             TEXT = "xyz",
             COUNT1 = results.Where(a => a.TOPLAM_FIYAT != null).Count(),
             COUNT2 = results.Where(a => a.TOPLAM_FIYAT == null).Count()
         }).Single();
```

Answer (score 0):

Just complementing on @sgmoore's answer, you can place you filter condition inside the `.Count` method itself:

```
var value = new  CHART_MODEL
{
    TEXT = "xyz",
    COUNT1 = query.Count(a => a.TOPLAM_FIYAT != null),
    COUNT2 = query.Count(a => a.TOPLAM_FIYAT == null) 
};
```

There is the new `is null` and `is not null` syntax introduced in C#9. It reads really nice, but it is still [not recommended by Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/linq/handle-null-values-in-query-expressions) to use in Linq-to-SQL.